# SharePoint Application feasibility with JMETER

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, poc

I have been facing issue with JMeter recently where I needed to understand if JMeter supports SharePoint Application?

I am stuck at the recording of a simple Login-Logout page where ADID Authentication is involved, whenever I try to record in the following manner it gets stuck on the ADID Popup only:

1. Hit HomePage
2. ADID Pop-up window (here when I enter valid credentials it just asks for the same thing)

Can anyone guide me if there is something that needs to be done in order to work it with JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Figure out what authentication method is being used under the hood, like [Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager), or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)). Just ask around or inspect request/response headers using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
2. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and properly configure it for the required authentication type, see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for example setup

You can also use an alternative recording solution like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi), but you will still need the HTTP Authorization Manager in order to properly replay the recorded script